# Is index and position of a number in a series, the same thing?

Tags: java, arrays, math

I got a bit confused with the position and index of a number. The confusion started when some say the 10th number of Fibonacci series is 34. While we know that F(10)=55.
They actually started counting from 1 and I did it with 0 as the first number is 0. Though frankly speaking it was not an array so there is no hard rule that you have to start from 0 itself.

I know arrays have index that starts with 0 and even there if someone says print the position and index of a number should I write `pos= i + 1` for the position or the index is itself the position.
That is should I say that nth position is the (n+1)th number.

For instance 10th position in a Fibonacci series is the 11th number ?

Any help with this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say it depends on conventions. Decide with whoever you need to communicate with whether the first position is 0 or 1 and be consistent.

Comment: Starting from 0 is typically due to how arrays initially worked in C and derived languages, since an array of `int` `a[x]` gives an address of `a + x*sizeof(int)` (can also be written like that in C), thus having `x=0` gives the address of `a`.  Note that Fibonacci can start as '1,1,...' or '0, 1, 1...'. In maths usually you can get a clue from the context, like a series Un starting at U0 or U1, or it's a convention, as said @Federico.

Comment: `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55` - the first number is 0. This is zero-based *indexing* in programming (Commonly misattributed to Dijkstra, who thought "GTE" was too hard to read/understand, but actually became prevalent due to an attempt to mess with someone's yacht... the story is on some blog somewhere in the internet ether). Using 0-based *indexing*, `55` is the index value `f10` because indexing starts at `0` here (but not always, thankfully).